# Python range slicing and indexing behavior

Tags: python, slice

In Python, I'm wondering why slices work the way they do.  Why did Guido van Rossum define `a[start:end]` to include `a[start]` but *not* `a[end]`, or as in the title, why does `a[0:1]` only contain the first element and not the first two?

This seems like a step back from MATLAB's indexing behavior.

**EDIT**: The reason I asked this question is that it is confusing that `a[0:0]` is empty.  But I didn't design a popular language, so what do I know.

Comment: Because not including the end index fits neatly with 0-based indexing. `range(10)` produces the indices 0 through to 9, slicing with `sequence[:len(sequence)]` works, etc.

Comment: I note that MATLAB uses 1-based indexing, which means that closed-end indexing makes some sense. You won't get the nice `a == a[:end] + a[end:]` invariant we have in Python in MATLAB, however.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To [quote](https://plus.google.com/115212051037621986145/posts/YTUxbXYZyfi) Guido van Rossum himself:

> [...] I was swayed by the elegance of half-open intervals. Especially the
>   invariant that when two slices are adjacent, the first slice's end
>   index is the second slice's start index is just too beautiful to
>   ignore. For example, suppose you split a string into three parts at
>   indices i and j -- the parts would be a[:i], a[i:j], and a[j:].

Comment: Ahhh... okay, so there is some method to the madness :)

Comment: +1, you should add this to the question this one duplicates

Answer (score 0):

`a[start:end-1]` allows you to use `a[0:len(a)]`.

And it fits with all other functions such as `range()`, and others.

Comment: Surely you would always use `[:]` in that scenario? But the point about using `len(a)` as `stop` is valid, e.g. for `range`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe You are correct, but this is just an example that is easy for him to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Python indexing is 0-based. By *excluding* the end value, most slicing and `range()` operations can naturally reflect the *number* of items sliced or produced while still including index 0.

Thus, `range(10)` produces 10 elements, from 0 through to 9. Slicing to with `sequence[:1]` produces 1 element, index 0.

Moreover, not including the end index makes it easier to use the *same value* as a start for a next section. Thus `sequence[:i] + sequence[i:]` re-creates `sequence` from two slices without having to adjust `i`.